# how to change the background color of the particular row in python Django

Tags: python, django

the below code is table.py

```
 class StColumn(tables.Column):
     def render(self, value, record):
       if record.status == 'warning':
          self.attrs ={"td": {"bgcolor": "DeepSkyBlue"}}
      elif record.status == 'ok':
          self.attrs ={"td": {"bgcolor": "SandyBrown"}}
      return u"%s" % (record.status.id)
class resultTable(BaseTable):
class Meta(BaseTable.Meta):
    model = resultModel
    attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover row-color=green' , 'width': '70%'}
    status= StColumn(accessor='status.id')
    print(status)
    fields = (
        "field1",
        "field2",
        "field3",
        "status",
        "field5",
    )
```

**how we can change the color of row when the status==warning and status ==ok **

Answer (score 1):

Display logic should not be handled in the view but in your templates instead. Take a look at this documentation for further information:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Typically you would display data from your model through the use of Views and HTML templates. You would write a view function/class that gets called when a user goes to a particular URL. That view would use a queryset to pass the data from your model into the template. Going into that much detail here would be pretty wasteful as there is a TON of documentation available describing this process.

Basically you would need a view that looks kind of like this:

```
def your_view(request):
    your_instances = YourModel.objects.all()
    context = {
        'your_instances': your_instances,
    }
    return render(request, 'your_html_template.html', context=context)
```

Then your template would look something like this:

```
<table>
  {% for instance in your_instances %}
    {% if instance.status == 'warning' %}
      <tr style="background-color:#FF0000">
    {% endif %}
    {% if instance.status == 'ok' %}
      <tr style="background-color:#000000">
    {% endif %}
        <td>{{ instance.field }}</td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: can you provide the correct logic ..or correct way

Comment: @renu The answer is more a guide for you to accomplish your code, you should implement the logic not us.

Comment: @brandonris thanks for code ...here i forgotten to mention we have used one table for all the product ...we only pass the filed to the html template for table. Every  plugins has own table.py file to pass the model name and table filed